# Возможно ли получить доступ к какому-нибудь индексу массива, хранящегося в ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<int[]> trick= new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] array = new int[3];
        for(int s = 0; s < array.length;s++){
            array[s] = s;
        }trick.add(array);
    }
}Возможно ли, как-нибудь, получить доступ к (например) array[2]?
```

Comment: сначала получаете доступ к trick, а потом у него уже и получаете доступ к массиву

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно.

```
int a = trick.get(i)[j];
```